# Retrieve records with $_POST

Tags: php

I have a bit of a problem. I have a navbar

```
|  home  |  view  |  view(active)  |  view(deleted)  |
```

When I click on view, I am taken to `view.php` which just retrieves all database records with:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory
```

In my inventory table, I have a column called `status` that has a value of either `y` or `n`. (`y` for active, `n` for not active (or deleted)).

When I click on the `view(active)` and `view(deleted)` links I want to execute different queries, such as these:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status LIKE 'y' (for retrieval of active records)  
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status LIKE 'n' (for retrieval of deleted records)
```

It works fine if I attach `?view=y` to the end of my `view.ph`p link. The form action of my form references itself (`view.php`) except with the view type attached to it: `?view=y` or `?view=n` and then having conditionals determine which mysql query to execute. However, I would like to handle this situation with POST and it's not working. I don't want any values in my URL. Works just fine with `$_GET` though.

Thanks.

**CODE (view.php conditionals for queries)**

```
    if ($_POST['view'] == "y") {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status LIKE 'y'"); }
    else if ($_POST['view'] == "n")  {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status LIKE 'n'"); }
    else if ($_POST['submit'] == "search") {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE descrip LIKE '%$searchString%'"); }
    else {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory"); }
```

**CODE (my navigation bar)**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="add.php"><input type="button" value="ADD" /></a>
    <a href="view.php"><input type="button" value="VIEW" /></a>
    <a href="view.php?view=y"><input type="button" value="view active" /></a>
    <a href="view.php?view=n"><input type="button" value="view deleted" /></a>
    <div><br />
        <form action="view.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="searchDescription" id="search" placeholder="search for text in description" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchDescription']; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" name="submit" id="searchDescriptionButton" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hidden input types to pass POST parameters to your php script. There are a lot of more elegant solutions, but here is one that requires minimum code change.

Add `<input type="hidden" name="view" id="viewvalue">` in your form, and have your buttons call a javascript function that sets the value to `y` or `n` and submits the form.

```
<script>
function setView(wanted)
{
   document.getElementById("viewvalue").value = wanted;
   document.getElementById("viewform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Note that this function assumes that you have given the id `viewform` to your form.

Then change the links in your buttons' `a href` to `javascript:setView('y')` and `javascript:setView('n)`, and you should be set.

EDIT : Since you cannot use javascript, here is what it should look like

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="add.php"><input type="button" value="ADD" /></a>
<a href="view.php"><input type="button" value="VIEW" /></a>
<form name="viewactiveform" action="view.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="y">
    <input type="submit" value="view active" />
</form>
<form name="viewdeletedform" action="view.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="n">
    <input type="submit" value="view deleted" />
</form>
<div><br />
    <form action="view.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="searchDescription" id="search" placeholder="search for text in description" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchDescription']; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" name="submit" id="searchDescriptionButton" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this - You can add a form to your page for that purpose with hidden field to store post value (y, n)

```
<form name="gotoview" action="view.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="view" id="view" value="" />
</form>
```

Your links should post the form

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['gotoview'].view='n';document.forms['gotoview'].submit();">View discontinued</a>
```

Use JavaScript to populate the hidden field, then post the form to the url in action.

Comment: Boss doesn't want JavaScript unfortunately. It's not my decision, I'd go with that but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter if you're doing a POST, if the value you're passing is part of the requested page's URL, then it'll be in $_GET.

One quick/dirty/bad workaround is to simply use $_REQUEST, which is a combination of _GET and _POST, but it's not recommended, as there's no guaranteed as to how your PHP is configured and which method will take priority. e.g. having

```
<form action="example.php?somevar=value" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="somevar" value="othervalue" />
</form>
```

is indeterminate, depending on your PHP install's `variable_order` setting.

And note that `somefield LIKE 'someconstantvalue'` is somewhat pointless, being the exact equivalent of `somefield='someconstantvalue'`. LIKE is used for wildcard searches and generally should'be mixed with constant value comparisons.

Comment: The search is because I grab the search text, store it in `$searchString`, and then search for that phrase within "description". If the search matches a word in 1 or more rows description, those records along with all others are retrieved. It works fine. Thanks for your input, I'll just use `$_GET` lol too much hassle.